# Best way to move data between tables and generate mapping of old to new identity values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, identity-column

I need to merge data from 2 tables into a third (all having the same schema) and generate a mapping of old identity values to new ones. The obvious approach is to loop through the source tables using a cursor, inserting the old and new identity values along the way. Is there a better (possibly set-oriented) way to do this?

**UPDATE**: One additional bit of info: the destination table already has data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your mapping table with an IDENTITY column for the new ID.  Insert from your source tables into this table, creating your mapping.

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for your target table.

Insert into the target table from your source tables joined to the mapping table, then `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`.

Comment: when you create the identity on the mapping table, set the seed so that it doesn't conflict with existing data.

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) states: `Be cautious about using IDENT_CURRENT to predict the next generated identity value. The actual generated value may be different from IDENT_CURRENT plus IDENT_INCR because of insertions performed by other sessions.` Is there a way to reliably avoid clashing identity values?

Comment: This seems a bit ugly, but maybe it's the best that can be done. I _really_ wish this was possible using the OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 2):

I created a mapping table based on the `OUTPUT` clause of the `MERGE` statement. No `IDENTITY_INSERT` required.

In the example below, there is `RecordImportQueue` and `RecordDataImportQueue`, and `RecordDataImportQueue.RecordID` is a FK to `RecordImportQueue.RecordID`. The data in these staging tables needs to go to `Record` and `RecordData`, and FK must be preserved.

RecordImportQueue to Record is done using a `MERGE` statement, producing a mapping table from its `OUTPUT`, and RecordDataImportQueue goes to `RecordData` using an `INSERT` from a SELECT of the source table joined to the mapping table.

```
DECLARE @MappingTable table ([NewRecordID] [bigint],[OldRecordID] [bigint])

MERGE [dbo].[Record] AS target
USING (SELECT [InstanceID]
            ,RecordID AS RecordID_Original
            ,[Status]
        FROM [RecordImportQueue]
        ) AS source
ON (target.RecordID = NULL) -- can never match as RecordID is IDENTITY NOT NULL.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([InstanceID],[Status])
    VALUES (source.[InstanceID],source.[Status])
    OUTPUT inserted.RecordID, source.RecordID_Original INTO @MappingTable;
```

After that, you can insert the records in a referencing table as folows:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RecordData]
    ([InstanceID]
    ,[RecordID]
    ,[Status])
SELECT [InstanceID]
    ,mt.NewRecordID -- the new RecordID from the mappingtable
    ,[Status]
FROM [dbo].[RecordDataImportQueue] AS rdiq
JOIN @MappingTable AS mt
ON rdiq.RecordID = mt.OldRecordID
```

Although long after the original post, I hope this can help other people, and I'm curious for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would temporarily add an extra column to the new table to hold the old ID. Once your inserts are complete, you can extract the mapping into another table and drop the column.

Comment: This assumes I can alter the schema of the target table, which I can, but I'm curious how this could be solved if that isn't possible.

Comment: @Daniel: Essentially, I'd use the same technique, but instead of altering the target table, I'd create a temp table that would consist of the target table's schema (including the identity column) plus the additional old ID column. Insert into the temp table, then use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewTable ON` and insert from the temp table to your new table. Remember to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewTable OFF` when you're done.

Comment: Couldn't you encounter clashing identity values when inserting into the target table?

Comment: Just noticed that my previous comment is basically the same as [adrift's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971830/best-way-to-move-data-between-tables-and-generate-mapping-of-old-to-new-identity/3972529#3972529)

Comment: @Daniel: As mentioned in [adrift's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971830/best-way-to-move-data-between-tables-and-generate-mapping-of-old-to-new-identity/3972529#3972529), set the initial seed of the identity in the temp table high enough to avoid existing values in your target table and you should be OK.